PublicKey (JDK) to ECPublicKey (BC)
I java a public key out of a X509 certificate.
I try to get it to an object of ECPublicKey of BouncyCastle.
Tried it with casting - gets casting exception.
void foo (X509Certificate cert)
{
   java.security.PublicKey pk = cert.getPublicKey ();
   org.bouncycastle.jce.interfaces.ECPublicKey ecpk = (ECPublicKey) pk;   // exception
}

How can I convert it to ECPublicKey?

To begin with, what class is it (pk.getClass())? PublicKey is just an interface.

I found this - works.
X509EncodedKeySpec spec = new X509EncodedKeySpec (cert.getPublic ().getEncoded ());
KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance ("EC");
ECPublicKey ecpk = (ECPublicKey) kf.generatePublic (spec);


Why would that work? Are you saying ecpk is an org.bouncycastle.jce.interfaces.ECPublicKey? There's nothing being done here to explicitly select the BC provider, so why would a BC object get returned?

Yes, you are right. I added BC as crypto provider before. But did not mention it in the code.

The current answer leaves too many points open for future readers. Even if you add BC as a provider, it does not work: https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/1fkV. For it to work, you would have to specify the BC provider in the KeyFactory, e.g. https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/1fkW. Alternatively, the BouncyCastle provider would have to be inserted before the SunEC provider (e.g. with insertProviderAt(): https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/1fkX) or the SunEC provider would have to be removed (removeProvider()). However, as this is not self-explanatory, you should explain this in your answer.
